# Cant input data to database with PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo

im trying to input data to database with PDO,i make a form for users to input,so forminput -> inputprocess.

But i cant input coz when i press submit its going to proses_input.php and show blank page.
I try to write the code in 1 file but when i press submit it show the input form again.

Here is my form_input.php

```
<form method="POST" action="proses_input.php">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <td> : </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="nama" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>No. Pegawai</td>
        <td> : </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="no_pegawai" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bagian</td>
        <td> : </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="bagian">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jabatan</td>
        <td> : </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="jabatan">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" value="submit">Input</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

and here is my proses_input.php

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $no_pegawai = $_POST['no_pegawai'];
    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $bagian = $_POST['bagian'];
    $jabatan = $_POST['jabatan'];

    try { //KONDISI
        $sql = "INSERT INTO phonebook (no_pegawai, nama, bagian, jabatan) 
            VALUES (:no_pegawai, :nama, :bagian, :jabatan)";
    $input = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $input->bindparam(':no_pegawai', $no_pegawai);
    $input->bindparam(':nama', $nama);
    $input->bindparam(':bagian', $bagian);
    $input->bindparam(':jabatan', $jabatan);

    $input->execute();

        header('location: admin.php');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

IDK why but everytime i input data to my form,its always stuck on proses_input.php with blank page.i already try to put it in one php file but still not works. Pls help me,thanks

Comment: `bindparam` - should I think be `bindParam` ~ look at the PHP error log &/or turn on error reporting

Comment: change `<button type="submit" value="submit">Input</button>` to `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">`

Comment: What have you tried to debug this problem? Have you tried to check which input arrives at your script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above you haven't named your button, therefore it won't match the condition `isset($_POST["submit"])` because there is no field named "submit" in your `$_POST` array. Also worth noting that you should not rely on users input. I saw that you are using parameterized query which is nice but don't forget to escape these values when displaying them on the UI to avoid XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: thanks so much, i dont realize that,coz i want a stylish button to submit